# Cannot create direct link to image hosted online

Tags: html, image

I was just trying to add a background image from http://wallpaperswide.com/rocky_peak-wallpapers.html to my website.

The link to the particular image is http://wallpaperswide.com/download/rocky_peak-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg.

However, if I try to load the image from the second link, it doesn't load. If I paste the URL into my browser, it redirects me to the first link.

Why does this happen? Thanks.

**Edit**

I'm getting some answers that there is an HTTP redirect. I know I can download the file and use locally.

However, the problem is that I'm writing a script that dynamically takes an image from the wallpaperswide.com site and automatically getting the image that fits the person's screen resolution. I just scan the page for the links and try to use those links. I can't download every image from the site and have them locally...

Any suggestions?

Comment: the admins of that website did this on purpose, in order to avoid having people link directly to their images, because [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_linking#Controversial_uses_of_inline_linking). your ability to hotlink their images is bad for their business, and hard on their servers, and possibly a breach of copyright etc, which is why they have chosen to prevent you from doing so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `http://wallpaperswide.com/download/rocky_peak-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg` is not an image, it's a document.

HTTP urls always point to documents, therefore the web server is able to process it and give you the appropriate result.

Comment: How is it that the `.jpg` extension is an (HTML?) document? Doesn't it mean that it has to be an image file? What do you mean by "document"?

Comment: And do you have any suggestions to get the raw image?

Comment: HTML urls does not neccessary point to a filesystem file, there's always a web server processing the requests behind. For the webserver, you are requesting the document "download/rocky_peak-wallpaper-1920x1080.jpg", but it doesn't have to exists as a file to be processed. I think you must check the cookies that are sent within the request from their website to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

The website author has added a 302 redirect rule while accessing the links directly, so you can't embed that link directly. Instead, you can download and refer it.

Comment: as some one pointed out it, this is done deliberately by the site owner and you cant embed those images.